# Ionic List is Not Updating with new data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple Ionic app which consists of a list like this:

```
  <ion-list ng-controller="MainController">
          <ion-item ng-repeat="task in tasks">
          {{task.title}}
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

In the MainController I add a new item to the tasks collection:

```
.controller('MainController',function($scope,$ionicPopup){

  $scope.tasks = [{title:"Clean dishes"},{title :"File Tax"},{title :"Take Pictures"}]; 

  $scope.task = new Object(); 

  $scope.showAddNewTaskDialog = function() {

    var popup = $ionicPopup.show({
        template:'<label class="item item-input"> <input ng-model="task.title" type="text" placeholder="Enter Task"/></label>', 
        title: 'New Task',
        scope: $scope, 
        buttons :[
          { text :'Cancel'}, 
          {
            text: '<b>Save</b>', 
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {

              $scope.tasks.push({ title :'new entry'});

            }
          }

        ]

    });

  }

})
```

But even though I am adding a new item in the tasks the list never refreshes.

Comment: did you check that onTap is firing ?

Comment: I have tested your code, its working fine, also added model value task.title in list.

Comment: works for me too: http://plnkr.co/edit/M4jp0SlS69QRkSdr9kbu